# My Projects Plugins not working after upgraded to API level 28

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I have changed my project API Level to 28 from 26 by adding :

```
preference name=android-minSdkVersion value=21
preference name=android-targetSdkVersion value=28
```

in `config.xml`.

After this any of the plugin of my project not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the preference tags like this:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
<preference name="android-targetedSdkVersion" value="28" />
```